# Entity Framework: ways to reduce roundtrips?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

New to EF, I'm trying to understand if I can give up stored procedures for basic crud operations. For example, how can you achieve an "insert or update" logic without having two roundtrips?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported in EF6. Insert operation is expected to return an ID for a new record, and an Update is expected to return mostly a timestamp for the concurrency detection mechanism. You may be able to map both operations to the same sproc, and just not use the returned ID in the Update, but the stored procedure for that will be needlessly complicated.

I suggest you don't get lazy, and split the different concerns to different procedures. It will be easier to maintain your code going forward.

Oh, and certainly you can't achieve what you want without using sprocs. EF will generate an `INSERT` for each record in the `Added` state, and an `UPDATE` for each record in the `Modified` state.

Comment: Doesn't the AddOrUpdate do exactly that (insert or update) ?

Comment: I didn't know about this, because I didn't use EF Migrations (which is what AddOrUpdate is intended for). There's an interesting post about it here: https://www.michaelgmccarthy.com/2016/08/24/entity-framework-addorupdate-is-a-destructive-operation/